# Crash on below 6.0 OS after opening my app with fingerprint support

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fingerprint-api

i added fingerprint support in my app. for that i used the below code.

```
 Fingerprint fingerprintManager = 
    (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
```

and i successfully integrated fingerprint with my app in 6.0 OS versions. but i tried to install and open the app in below 6.0 OS versions like 4.0, 5.0.

i tried to open the app 4.4.2 device it get crashes. and then i just used the COMPAT.

```
 Fingerprint fingerprintManager = 
    (FingerprintManagerCompat) FingerprintManagerCompat.from(mActivity)
```

using the above scenario i got successfully installed on 6.0 devices but in belowcrashes on below 6.0 devices. any other method to solve the crash on below 6.0 devices.

Comment: Provide crash from LogCat

Comment: It's clear that it failes with `FingerprintManager` below API23, because that was only added in API23. To know what went wrong with `FingerprintManagerCompat` we need to see the logcat.